# auto width in google visualization

Tags: javascript, c#, google-visualization

I have used below code to show scroll bar in google visualization when the char is large,

```
stringBuilder.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                    stringBuilder.Append(" chart.draw(view, {width: 660, height: 500, title: 'Title',");
                    stringBuilder.Append("legend: {position: 'none'},");
                    stringBuilder.Append("hAxis: {title: 'Resource', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'},slantedText:false},width:'data.getNumberOfRows() * 130',colors: ['DeepSkyBlue','green'],");

                    stringBuilder.Append("vAxis:{title: 'Effort (Hr)',titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'}}");
```

when using  width:'data.getNumberOfRows() * 130' it is not working, when set width a number it works, how do I set this?

Comment: You should probably check the generated Javascript and post it in the answer. There doesn't seem to be anything related to C# in this snippet

Comment: BTW `width:'data.getNumberOfRows() * 130'` as width a string value that contains `'data.getNumberOfRows() * 130'`. Perhaps the library can parse  and execute this, but I doubt it

Answer (score 2):

you're passing a "string", instead of a "calculation"

remove the apostrophe's...

`width: data.getNumberOfRows() * 130`

Comment: we are using stringbuilder to create script, when not using apostophe char not showing

Comment: my mistake I mean chart

Comment: check the console for errors? do you know how many rows there will be -- provide the result of the calc up front? instead of apostrophes, try wrapping with parenthesis -- I tested in JavaScript, should work, I can provide example if needed...